# Phone number lookup program: (index) and while loop

Tags: python

Can anybody please explain this code a little bit for me about why are we using the (index) and while loop?

```
def main():
    people = ['todd','david','angela','steve','bob','josh','ben']
    phoneNumbers = ['234-7654','567-1234','888-8745','789-5489','009-7566','444-6990','911-9111']

    found = False
    index = 0

    searchValue = raw_input('Enter a name to search for phone number: ')

    while found == False and index < len(people):
        if people[index] == searchValue:
            found = True
        else:
            index = index + 1

    if found:
        print('the phone number is: ',phoneNumbers[index])
    else:
        print('that name was not found')

main()
```

Comment: What's exactly the matter? explain better and clarify in th BODY o the answer and not in the TITLE,

Comment: Ask yourself: what is the initial value of `index`? When does `index` get incremented and why? How is `index` used? But actually at a closer look this piece of code doesn't make any sense unless one assumes that the name at position `i` has telephone number at the same position. Send the code back to its author asking for clarifications!

Comment: instead of `found == False` use `(not found)`, after `found = True` add `break` on new line, then you can delete the `else:` line and unindent the index increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is looping through the whole list of `phoneNumbers` and `people`. Each item on a list has its own index value. In python, the first item in the list has an index of 0. According to your question, indexes were used to find at which position the person's name is. Then the same index position is used to find what is the phone number in the other list. But to determine this, we have builtin method to find the index position of an item in a list. I have made modifications to your code and now it is optimized.`people.index(searchValue)`returns the index position of the `searchValue`. For example, if the `searchValue` is `steve`, then the index position we get will be `3`. We need to use this index position to find the phone number in the other list. So to do that we can simply do `phoneNumbers[people.index(searchValue)]` that simply means `phoneNumbers[3]`. This returns the 4th item which is `789-5489` that is the phone number.

**NOTE:**

- Index of a list always starts with `0`
- `listName.index(item)` returns the index position
- `listName[index]` returns the item

```py
def main():
    people = ['todd','david','angela','steve','bob','josh','ben']
    phoneNumbers = ['234-7654','567-1234','888-8745','789-5489','009-7566','444-6990','911-9111']

    searchValue = input('Enter a name to search for phone number: ')

    if searchValue in people:
        print(f"The phone number is {phoneNumbers[people.index(searchValue)]}")
    else:
        print('that name was not found')

main()
```

**Some information about the logic:**

- `while found == False` means until the name is found in the list
- `and index < len(people)` means the number of iterations that should
  take place in the list `people`
- `if people[index] == searchValue` checks if the person in the list is
  same as the person the user searched for
- `found = True` means that the person that we are looking for has been found. This will quit from the while loop because we mentioned that we
  need to execute the code only when `found = false`. But now it is
  true. So it will quit from the while loop
- `else: index = index + 1` is to shift to the next position. We
  already completed checking if the first item is equivalent to the
  user input. If it is not equal, then we need to check if the next
  name in the list is equal to the user input.

Keep in mind that only one of `if` or `else` will occur. That means when the condition for `if` **is satisfied**, only the `if` part will occur and the `else` part is not to be bothered. When the condition for `if` is **not satisfied**, only `else` will occur. Therefore, if the name is not found only we are checking the next item. If we found it, we are just going to quit from the `while` loop.

Comment: And why in else we do index = index+1?

Comment: The reason why we use `index = index + 1` is to shift to the next position. Imagine, we don't have that statement. The program will be checking if the first item is equivalent for infinite number of times. And there is no point. To shift to the next name only we are using `index=index+1`. Let us know if that answered your doubt

Comment: I did my assignment and sent it to my professor he sent this back to me with index = index+1 i mean I know how the operation works but Im confused by the logic. Like in the code either IF happens or ELSE so if (IF) happens then why (ELSE) dammit i m confused

Comment: I will edit my answer to explain about the logic of that part as well.

Comment: why use an `r` string if you only have A-Za-z chars

Comment: @rioV8 the question had `raw_input` included. But as you correctly mentioned, there is no need for raw input.

Comment: @NikayelJohn I edited my answer with few other information. Let us know if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

In `while found == False and index < len(people):`, `found == False` means run until find a name, and `index < len(people)` means searched every name from list.

And the reason using `index` is phone number locates at same index in `phonenumbers`.

Comment: Yeah and why do we use index = index+1 although it doesnt run I guess

Comment: @NikayelJohn You can check it simply. Add `print(index)` in while loop. It will increase.

Comment: You write: "_the reason using_ `index` _is phone number locates at same index in_  `phonenumbers`." And why is that so? Why didn't they use a dictionary instead? Let us learn to think before we learn to code!! This type of attitude is the same that might one day lead the OP to use Excel as a database. Or just blindly accept things "just because".